# Tutorial Exercise - C-x C-s Save -- Write Protected issue in OSX

Tags: osx, auto-save, directory

I'm making my way through the tutorial and have run into an issue when trying to do the exercise on saving a file:

```
Saving file /~TUTORIAL...
basic-save-buffer-2: Directory / write-protected
Auto-saving...
Auto-saving ~TUTORIAL: Opening output file: Permission denied, /#~TUTORIAL#
```

The machine is mine, and so I have access everywhere, I think, and believe that I'm in my user directory to begin with.

Any ideas? Do I have to run the command as root?

Comment: Is there a typo? It looks like you are trying to save the file "~TUTORIAL" at the root of the system ("/") instead of saving the file "TUTORIAL" in your home directory (" ~/ ")

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I somehow got out of ~/ and into root. I quite emacs and relaunched and the save exercise worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @jerome you should write an answer with that suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on a typo: `/~` instead of `~/`. Not really an Emacs question (except possibly for someone unfamiliar with `/` and `~` in UNIX or GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to save the file `~TUTORIAL` at the root of the system (`/`) instead of saving the file `TUTORIAL` in your home directory (`~/`).

Typically when you open a new file Emacs will suggest directory based on the active buffer; however that is only a suggestion and you can always delete it, and enter something else. Emacs itself is not working "in" any directory.